# How to count a position of element, relative to another element using regex?

Tags: java, regex

Given String

```
//          1       2       3
String a = "letters.1223434.more_letters";
```

**I'd like to recognize that numbers come in a 2nd position after the first dot**

I then would like to use this knowledge to replace "2nd position of"

```
//          1         2           3
String b = "someWords.otherwords.morewords";
```

with "hello" to effectively make

```
//          1         2     3
String b = "someWords.hello.morewords";
```

Substitution would have to be done based on the original position of matched element in String a

How can this be done using regex please?

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to pull the number from string a?
Then also do the substitution in string b?

Comment: I'd like to recognize that numbers (say i match for numbers) are in 2nd position. Then, knowing that, i'd like to pull something of another string that is also on a 2nd position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding those numbers you can use group mechanism (round brackets in regular expresions):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

...

String data = "letters.1223434.more_letters";
String pattern="(.+?)\\.(.+?)\\.(.+)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(data);
if (m.find()) //or while if needed
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) 
    //group 0 == whole String, so I ignore it and start from i=1
        System.out.println(i+") [" + m.group(i) + "] start="+m.start(i));
// OUT:
//1) [letters] start=0
//2) [1223434] start=8
//3) [more_letters] start=16
```

BUT if your goal is just replacing text between two dots try maybe `replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)` method on String object:

```
//find ALL characters between 2 dots once and replace them 
String a = "letters.1223434abc.more_letters";
a=a.replaceFirst("\\.(.+)\\.", ".hello.");
System.out.println(a);// OUT => letters.hello.more_letters
```

`regex` tells to search all characters between two dots (including these dots), so `replacement` should be ".hello." (with dots).

If your String will have more dots it will replace ALL characters between first and last dot. If you want regex to search for minimum number of characters necessary to satisfy the pattern you need to use Reluctant Quantifier ->`?` like:

```
String b = "letters.1223434abc.more_letters.another.dots";
b=b.replaceFirst("\\.(.+?)\\.", ".hello.");//there is "+?" instead of "+"
System.out.println(b);// OUT => letters.hello.more_letters.another.dots
```

Comment: What if the pattern matches the *first* word? The first word has no preceding dot, so your `".word."` logic would fail. Hint: use a "look around" regex

Comment: @Bohemian From what I see in question, String doesn't have dot at the beginning so first word can't match pattern "dotCharsDot". At the beginning (and end) of regex I used "\\." to point that matching string must contain dots at begging and end, so replacement also must contain this dots, or they will disappear after replacing.

Comment: I think your algorithm is flawed. We can discuss it forever, or you can run a test where the match hits the first word (`"letters"` in OP's example) and see if your code works. I recommend running the test, which will immediately prove/disprove my belief.

Comment: @Bohemian Judging by your reputation I assume you are right. But I am just newbie with only basic knowledge of Java and regex and simply don't understand my mistake (can't imagine String similar to String from question which will generate incorrect match/output for my regex). I would be very grateful if you could write some code example pointing my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not directly possible in RegExp, because you cannot get access to the number of the capture group and use this in the replacement operation.

Two alternatives:

- If you can use any programming language: Split a using regexp into groups. Check each group if it matches your numeric identifier condition. Split the b string into groups. Replace the corresponding match.
- If you only want to use a number of regexp, then you can concatenate a and b using a unique separator (let's say |). Then match `.*?\.\d+?\..*?|.*?\.(.*?)\..*?` and replace `$1`. You need to apply this regexp in the three variations first position, second position, third position.

Answer (score 0):

the regex for string a would be

```
\w+\.(\d+)\.\w+
```

using the match group to grab the number.

the regex for the second would be

```
\w+\.(\w+)\.\w+
```

to grab the match group for the second string.

Then use code like this to do what you please with the matches.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
```

where patternStr is the pattern I mentioned above and inputStr is the input string.

You can use variations of this to try each combination you want. So you can move the match group to the first position, try that. If it returns a match, then do the replacement in the second string at the first position. If not, go to position 2 and so on...